# set RowElement.BackColor in Telerik RadGridView (WinForms) in RowFormatting event

Tags: telerik, radgridview, backcolor

Is there some trick to setting the back color of the row in the Telerik WinForms RadGridView at runtime in the RowFormatting event? I am able to set the RowElement.Font in this event but not the RowElement.BackColor. I have stepped through the code in the debugger and am certain that the line is being executed (the event is properly "wired up").

```
void grid_RowFormatting(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.RowFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
         if   (e.RowElement.RowInfo.Cells["CODE"].Value.ToString() == "X"))
                {
                    // the following line is executed but has no apparent effect
                    e.RowElement.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
                }

     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good, you just need to set `DrawFill` to `true`
Add this:

```
e.RowElement.DrawFill = true;
```

Full example:

```
void grid_RowFormatting(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.RowFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
         if   (e.RowElement.RowInfo.Cells["CODE"].Value.ToString() == "X"))
                {   
                     e.RowElement.DrawFill = true;  
                     e.RowElement.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
                }

     }
```